# How do you make a binary search tree in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

In Scheme, I can use `define-struct` to make a binary search tree, but how do you do it in Clojure?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use structmaps.  To define one:

```
(defstruct bintree :left :right :key)
```

To make an instance:

```
(struct-map bintree :left nil :right nil :key 0)
```

You can then access the values in the struct like this:

```
(:left tree)
```

etc.

Or you can create new accessor functions:

```
(def left-branch (accessor bintree :left))
```

and use it:

```
(left-branch tree)
```

Comment: How is this better than using a nested list or vector?

Comment: It's better because the keys are named and they have guaranteed constant-time access (lists are linear access, though vectors are constant). Though this was written in 2009, and a lot has changed since then. I was only recommending `defstruct` because the question was about scheme's `define-structure`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Clojure, but I bet it's the same way you do it in Scheme without `define-struct` ... just cons together the left and right branches. To find something, recurse until you hit an atom.

Seriously, though, structmaps sound like what you want. I found [this page](http://clojure.org/data_structures). Look for structmaps about half way down.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use the tree that is already defined in language (every sorted-map is a tree really, if you just need different function to compare keys, use sorted-map-by).

```
;;define function for comparing keys
(defn compare-key-fn [key1 key2] (< key1 key2) )

;;define tree and add elements
(def my-tree
  (->                              ;;syntax sugar
    (sorted-map-by compare-key-fn) ;;this returns empty tree with given function to compare keys
    (assoc 100  "data for key = 100") ;;below we add elements to tree
    (assoc 2  "data for key = 2")
    (assoc 10 "data for key = 10")
    (assoc -2 "data for key = -1")))

;;accesing  elements by key
(prn "element for key 100 =" (my-tree 100))

;;"erasing" elements from tree - in reality, what we are really doing, is returning a new tree that contains all elements of the old one, except the element we've just erased.
(def my-new-tree
  (dissoc my-tree 2))

(prn my-new-tree) ;; to verify, that element 2 is "erased"
```

Comment: Not sorted-set? I think that would be a better fit, and the key could be part of the structs you store. sorted-map forces you to separate out the key and handle it separately forever.

Comment: +1 anyway, it's close to what I would have said, had I seen the question back when it was asked.