# Representing A Tree in Clojure

Tags: data-structures, clojure

What would be an idiomatic way to represent a tree in Clojure? E.g.:

```
     A
    / \
   B   C
  /\    \
 D  E    F
```

Performance is not important and the trees won't grow past 1000 elements.

Comment: WTF is wrong with you people, every time someone doesn't like the question they hit close. stackoverflow was a very good place to learn something now it has turned in to digg, with a lot of idiots. If you don't like the question thats what down vote is for.

Comment: They voted to close it, because it's an exact duplicate.

Comment: Agreed; this isn't about *liking* the question; as you say re learning something - perhaps learn from the last time somebody asked the same question?

Comment: The appropriate thing to do would be to downvote AND ADD A COMMENT POINTING OUT THE REASON. If you're community-minded enough to do the former, you should do the latter too. Otherwise you're just being spiteful.

Comment: @MarcGravell – where's the duplicate? This was the top result on Google for "clojure trees" for me just now.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
'(A (B (D) (E)) (C (F)))
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a scary way of doing it using just `cons`:

```
(defn mktree 
  ([label l r] (cons label (cons l r))) 
  ([leaf] (cons leaf (cons nil nil))))
(defn getlabel [t] (first t))
(defn getchildren [t] (rest t))
(defn getleft [t] (first (getchildren t)))
(defn getright [t] (rest (getchildren t)))
```

Note that children isn't a list; it's a pair.  If your trees aren't just binary, you could make it a list.  use nil when there's no left or right child, of course.

Otherwise, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611157/how-do-you-make-a-binary-search-tree-in-clojure).

The tree in your picture:

```
(mktree 'A (mktree 'B (mktree 'D) (mktree 'E)) (mktree 'C nil (mktree 'F)))
```

Comment: it has first & rest in place of car cdr

Comment: thanks ;)  common lisp has both.  i'll edit.  it does have 'cons' though?

Comment: I think you should edit it to say "I only know common lisp". Common Lisp is not 'Lisp'. It's *a* Lisp.

Answer (score 3):

Trees underly just about everything in Clojure because they lend themselves so nicely to structural sharing in persistent data structure. Maps and Vectors are actually trees with a high branching factor to give them bounded lookup and insert time. So the shortest answer I can give (though it's not really that useful) is that I really recommend [Purely functional data structures by Chris Okasaki](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521663504) for a real answer to this question. Also Rich Hickey's video on Clojure data structures on blip.tv

```
(set 'A 'B 'C)
```