# Stumped with functional breadth-first tree traversal in Clojure?

Tags: algorithm, clojure, functional-programming

Say I have a tree defined as per the recommendation in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787708/representing-a-tree-in-clojure), although it's a vector in my case, which hopefully shouldn't matter (they're vectors in Programming Clojure book):

```
(def tree [1 [[2 [4] [5]] [3 [6]]]])
```

which should be something like:

```
      1
     / \
    2   3
   / \  |
  4   5 6
```

Now, I'd like to do a breadth-first traversal of the tree without any of the traditional means such as the queue, and instead use exclusively the stack to pass information around. I know this isn't the easiest route, but I'm doing it mostly as exercise. Also at this point I'm not planning to return a collection (I'll figure that out afterwards as exercise) but instead just print out the nodes as I travel through them.

My current solution (just starting out with Clojure, be nice):

```
(defn breadth-recur
  [queue]
  (if (empty? queue)
    (println "Done!")
    (let [collections (first (filter coll? queue))]
      (do
        ; print out nodes on the current level, they will not be wrapped'
        ; in a [] vector and thus coll? will return false
        (doseq [node queue] (if (not (coll? node)) (println node)))
        (recur (reduce conj (first collections) (rest collections)))))))
```

The last line is not working as intended and I'm stumped about how to fix it. I know exactly what I want: I need to peel each layer of vectors and then concatenate the results to pass into recur.

The issue I'm seeing is mostly a:

```
IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long
```

Basically **conj** doesn't like appending a vector to a long, and if I swap conj for **concat**, then I fail when one of the two items I'm concatenating isn't a vector. Both conj and concat fail when facing:

```
[2 [4] [5] [3 [6]]]
```

I feel like I'm missing a really basic operation here that would work both on vectors and primitives in both positions.

Any suggestions?

**Edit 1:**

The tree should actually be (thanks Joost!):

```
(def tree [1 [2 [4] [5]] [3 [6]]])
```

However we still haven't found a **breadth**-first solution.

Comment: Did you have a look at the source of the functions in [clojure.walk](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.walk) or the function [tree-seq](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/tree-seq)? They implement tree traversal and might be interesting to you.

Comment: @Gert: It's my impression that all of those are depth-first, correct? I also considered zippers, but then my brain started melting at the thought.

Comment: Ah yes, `clojure.walk` does depth-first traversal; I missed the breadth-first requirement in your post, oops!

Comment: see clojure.zip and clojure.walk for possibly helpful info

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since apparently there is still no breadth-first solution posted, here is a simple algorithm, implemented first eagerly, and then transformed to be lazy:

```
(defn bfs-eager [tree]
  (loop [ret [], queue (conj clojure.lang.PersistentQueue/EMPTY tree)]
    (if (seq queue)
      (let [[node & children] (peek queue)]
        (recur (conj ret node) (into (pop queue) children)))
      ret)))

(defn bfs-lazy [tree]
  ((fn step [queue]
     (lazy-seq
      (when (seq queue)
        (let [[node & children] (peek queue)]
          (cons node
                (step (into (pop queue) children)))))))
   (conj clojure.lang.PersistentQueue/EMPTY tree)))
```

Comment: I'm curious, are you using a PersistentQueue simply because it's faster than a list?

Comment: We need to take from the front and add to the end. We could use a lazy sequence with concat, but this will fail if the tree is very large. So in some sense: yes, we could have used a list here. But aside from being much, much slower, it also doesn't express the intent: this is a queue, so why not use an actual queue structure?

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, both a vector and a list work as stacks (from different sides) if you use conj/pop, however with PersistentQueue you get to pop from the front and conj at the end?

Answer (score 13):

Your tree data is incorrect. It should be `[1 [2 [4] [5]] [3 [6]]]`

Also, you're mixing the tree traversal with printing and building up a result. Things get simpler if you concentrate on doing the hard part separately:

```
(def tree [1 [2 [4] [5]] [3 [6]]])
```

**NOTE THIS IS DEPTH-FIRST. SEE BELOW**

```
(defn bf "return elements in tree, breath-first"
   [[el left right]] ;; a tree is a seq of one element,
                     ;; followed by left and right child trees
   (if el
     (concat [el] (bf left) (bf right))))

(bf tree)
=> (1 2 4 5 3 6)
```

**CORRECT VERSION**

```
(defn bf [& roots] 
   (if (seq roots) 
       (concat (map first roots) ;; values in roots
               (apply bf (mapcat rest roots))))) ;; recursively for children

(bf tree)
=> (1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

Comment: That works, thanks! I forgot to mention that I was trying to solve the problem for the general case where there is no maximum number of children nodes, hence my attempt to reduce/into.

Also, is there any way to do that with a tail call?

Comment: `(defn bf [[el & children]] (if el (apply concat [el] (map bf children))))`

Comment: if you really want to you can transform that into a tail call. but I don't see the point since it's inherently stack-based and already lazy.

Comment: @Joost Diepenmaat: I have the same question as kotarak...  Isn't 1 2 4 5 3 6 DFS while a BFS should give 1 2 3 4 5 6?  I mean, it looks like OP constructed his tree precisely so that a BFS give back 1 2 3 4 5 6.  The Wikipedia article on BFS does the same with a 'a b c d e f g h'.  See animated gif here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Comment: @TacticalCoder, kotarak: I think you're right, we should be seeing 1 2 3 4 5 6. Late night, didn't even notice..
Taking off the answer for the time being.

Comment: For some reason I completely missed my error. Appended a correct version.

Comment: Note that using `concat` here means you will get a stack overflow for a large tree (whether deep or not), for example `(reduce (fn [tree node] [node tree]) [10000] (range 9999 0 -1))`.

Answer (score 1):

This might help, I was creating an algorithm to evaluate if a tree is symmetric and used a breadth-first traversal:

```
(defn node-values [nodes]
    (map first nodes))

(defn node-children [nodes]
  (mapcat next nodes))

(defn depth-traversal [nodes]
    (if (not (empty? nodes))
        (cons (node-values nodes) (depth-traversal (node-children nodes)))))

(defn tree-symmetric? [tree]
    (every?
        (fn [depth] (= depth (reverse depth)))
        (depth-traversal (list tree))))

(def tree '(1 (2 (3) (4)) (2 (4) (3))))
(node-values (list tree)) ; (1)
(node-children (list tree)) ; ((2 (3) (4)) (2 (4) (3)))
(depth-traversal (list tree)) ; ((1) (2 2) (3 4 4 3))
(tree-symmetric? tree) ; true
```

Answer (score 0):

many combinations of `reduce`and `conj` can be replaced with single `into` call
in the case above with reduce you may need to pass an initial empty vector to reduce to
get make conjunction happy.