# Printing levels of Tree in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have looked around already and I can't see to find a way to do this.
I simply want to print a tree out, level by level.

So `'[a [b c]]` would print out:

```
a
b c
```

Comment: Nobody? :P my head is completely battered for an answer!

Comment: I haven't. I'm looking at it, been doing it since 1pm. It's like there's a mental block going on. I come from a Java background I'm using Programming Clojure by Stuart Halloway but that's not been any help really.

Comment: @DanielJour sorry forgot to tag you...

Comment: Well, what you want is a breadth first traversal of a tree. I don't have the time to write an answer atm but you should be able to find something using that information.

Comment: @DanielJour I've already looked for that type of information and came up short ::

Comment: James, you'll probably need to use recursion, so if you don't understand that, study it, either in the Halloway book or elsewhere.  (I didn't *get* recursion until I worked through *The Little Schemer*--which is not a bad book for a beginning Clojure programmer.  At least some of it has been translated into Clojure on the web.)  However, it's not entirely clear what behavior you want.  What should the output be for `[a [b c] d [e f]]` be?  If it's "a b" on one line and "b c e f" on the next, that will be a little bit trickier.

Comment: @Mars for yours the output would be ad \n bc \n ef I understand recursion in Clojure too :)

Comment: @James, is the expected outcome that each "leaf" prints out on it's own line or (if more than one leaf) all same level leafs are on their own line?

Comment: @FrankC. It's more each level of the tree is printed out.

Comment: How is this a tree then?

Comment: The above example could be expanded on I guess. Imagine a tree with root a, expanding down so [[a [b c] d] [e f]] forgive me if my brackets are off a little. @MarcinBilski then I just want a function that prints each level of the tree. So root, then the two roots of the sub trees beneath etc

Comment: Still confused. What's the grammar? It seems that in a vector, the first element is the parent (on that level) followed by children or what?

Comment: I mean in [a [b c]], a is a root and b and c are children? But in [b c] both b and c are on the same level? 
This may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787708/representing-a-tree-in-clojure

Comment: say a is the root. b and c are children of root but respectively the roots of their own trees. Then e and f are children of c. Sorry I realise my example isn't accurate.

Comment: I've read through that, I still cannot figure out how to go through and print each level out.

Comment: Ok, forget it, I don't understand how to figure out what tree it represents. But let me see if I can rephrase your question: how to print nested vectors level by level. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it seems so. Forget about this specific tree. Imagine any tree such as the one in the example topic you sent me.  A would be printed, on a new line B C would be printed then on another new line D E F would be printed.

Comment: Have you tried pprint?

Comment: Might not be exactly what you want, but still might be good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided I understood you correctly, this code should work:

```
(defn bf
  [root] 
  (if (vector? root)
    (let [roots (filterv (complement vector?) root)
          children (filterv vector? root)]
      (if-not (empty? children)
        (into [roots] (mapcat bf children))
        [roots]))
    root))
```

It's not lazy, it returns a vector of vectors containing the nodes, e.g.

```
(bf ['a ['b 'c] 'd ['e 'f]]) => [[a d] [b c] [e f]]
```

Printing out:

```
(let [xs (bf ['a ['b 'c] 'd ['e 'f]])]
   (doseq [line (map str/join xs)] ; you need to require [clojure.string :as str]
     (println line)))
```

Comment: http://articles.leetcode.com/2010/09/printing-binary-tree-in-level-order.html This is what I mean Marcin, thank you for the effort though although that's what I need. I hope you'll derive better sense from that than you have from me :(

Comment: It all boils down to the representation you've chosen. I cannot make sense of it, sorry. That's why I suggested an alternative representation, a more canonical one as far as lisps are concerned. Doesn't my solution work for you? You just need to print each vector one by one.

Comment: If you look at the result, each vector correspons to one line you want to print out (e.g. [a d]).

Comment: So how would I print it out one vector at a time?

Comment: thank you, I'll see if this resembles what I need. It might need some tweaking but yeah :) although they print they're not necessarily on the same level.

Comment: Then I misunderstood your representation. I basically gather parents scattered around the vector (so for [a [b c] d] it would be a and d) and then recursively do the same for each child vector (in this example [b c]).

Comment: '[a [ b c [d e]] => a is root, b and c are children of a. d and e are children of c. There is three levels. Root (a) then b and c then d and e.

Comment: This is what the output looks like.

Comment: Glad to help. Pls. don't forget to accept the answer. :)